# Xcode 4 SFML 2 error

Tags: c++, sfml

I used the SFML 2 installer, it can be found here. http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php

```
Ld /Users/pjquinn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gangnam_style-ayfrlelgnycrzpdbmwbkqgtkkryv/Build/Products/Debug/gangnam_style.app/Contents/MacOS/gangnam_style normal x86_64
    cd /Users/pjquinn/Programming/C++/gangnam_style
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
-arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
-L/Users/pjquinn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gangnam_style-ayfrlelgnycrzpdbmwbkqgtkkryv/Build/Products/Debug
-F/Users/pjquinn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gangnam_style-ayfrlelgnycrzpdbmwbkqgtkkryv/Build/Products/Debug
-filelist /Users/pjquinn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gangnam_style-ayfrlelgnycrzpdbmwbkqgtkkryv/Build/Intermediates/gangnam_style.build/Debug/gangnam_style.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/gangnam_style.LinkFileList
-mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -lsfml-system-d -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-audio-d -lsfml-network-d -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -o /Users/pjquinn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gangnam_style-ayfrlelgnycrzpdbmwbkqgtkkryv/Build/Products/Debug/gangnam_style.app/Contents/MacOS/gangnam_style

ld: library not found for -lsfml-system-d clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I'm creating a project should I select the Use Frameworks box?

Answer (score 1):

[Debug binaries are not shipped with the installer.](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/212)

You should also have a look at [the other issues](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues)

Comment: For some reason setting the Suffix to "" keeps the error, what do you think this could mean?

Comment: @Patrick, by `Suffix` you mean `SFML_LINK_DYLIBS_SUFFIX` variable ? If yes, the error is exactly the same ?

Comment: Yep, that's the variable I mean, and yes, the error is the same.

Comment: Are you sure ? It's still looking for -lsfml-system**-d** ?

Comment: You should read more carefully the error message because it is not the same as before.
As I said, there are other issues (that are now fixed in the git version). One of them is [#233](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/233). You need to apply this fix to successfully build your project.

Comment: When will the final version be released?

Answer (score 0):

I used their template and checked the "Use Frameworks" box, but still had problems. What I ended up doing was adding the SFML frameworks files (which their installer script put in ~/Libraries/Frameworks) in the project myself (simple drag'n'drop). I double checked and made sure the added frameworks were then included in the Build Phases (which they were), and everything worked fine.